# WPF/C# MaterialDesignInXAML, how to binding content to string in controlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

when I want to use button with IconPack.

```
<Button Content="WindowMinimize" Style="{StaticResource WindowsControlButton}" />
```

like this. and change style by controltemplate

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="WindowsControlButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundMainBrush}"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>                            // here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I tried this. but `<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>` doesn't work with my expectation.
how can i do it? please help me.

I want to change kind in ControlTemplate using button's content.
_

Comment: Not doable your way, I'm afraid. You can achieve it e.g. by extending button with Kind property (of type MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.PackIcon*Kind), and binding to it in Template.

Comment: what error does it show?

Comment: Thank you **Maciek Ś.** I fixed using your solution.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is the subtle difference in the type between `PackIcon.Kind` and `Button.Content`. The former is an enum while the latter is a generic object.
In XAML when you type in `<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMinimize"/>` it is able to determine that the string "WindowMinimize" needs to be converted to the target type of `PackIconKind` because of the property it is being applied to. This process of converting strings to the appropriate target type is handled by [type converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/typeconverters-and-xaml).

In WPF, a `Button` derives from `ContentControl` so the `Content` property is simply a generic `object`. So when you set `<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>` it is not able to determine the conversion because, Content could be anything. It does not know how to convert a generic object to an enum. So even though there is a string in the Content property, it never attempts anything beyond a simple cast to the target enum type, and a generic string does not cast to an enum.

There are a couple of options.

- As the comments above suggested, you can explicitly set the enum value into the `Content` (the type should be `MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.PackIconKind`). This works because it will attempt to cast the value in the `Content` property to the target type of `PackIconKind`.

`<Button Content="{x:Static materialDesign:PackIconKind.WindowMinimize}" ... />`

- You can write a value converter to convert the value. This will require you to change your binding from a `TemplateBinding` to a relative source binding like this:

`<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}}"/>`